# Same Query returns different results (MySQL Group By)

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

This only happens for queries that force `GROUP BY` after `ORDER BY`.

### Goal:

Get *latest* `balance` for each `unit` for the given `cardID`.

### Table:

```
cardID  |  unit     |  balance  |  date
--------|-----------|-----------|--------------
A1      |  DEPOSIT  |  100      |  2016-05-01
A1      |  DEPOSIT  |  90       |  2016-05-02
A1      |  DEPOSIT  |  80       |  2016-05-03
A1      |  DEPOSIT  |  75       |  2016-05-04
A1      |  MINUTE   |  1000     |  2016-05-01
A1      |  MINUTE   |  900      |  2016-05-02
A1      |  MINUTE   |  800      |  2016-05-03
```

### Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT unit, balance
    FROM cardBalances
    WHERE cardID = 'A1'
    ORDER BY date DESC
) AS cb
GROUP BY cb.unit;
```

### Expected Result (MySQL v5.5.38):

```
unit     |  balance  
---------|-----------
DEPOSIT  |  75       
MINUTE   |  800
```

### Unexpected Result (MySQL v5.7.13):

```
unit     |  balance
---------|-----------
DEPOSIT  |  100
MINUTE   |  1000
```

After upgrading to MySQL v5.7.13, the result returns the initial balances; as if no deduction occurred for the given card.

Is this a bug in MySQL version?
Would you suggest any other, more reliable way to solve this?

Comment: See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in your use of the database.  MySQL is quite explicit that when you include columns in the `SELECT` clause in an aggregation query -- and they are not in the `GROUP BY` -- then they come from *indeterminate* rows.

Such syntax is specific to MySQL.  It is not only a bad idea to learn, but it simply normally not work in other databases.

You can do what you want in various ways.  Here is one:

```
SELECT cb.*
FROM cardBalances cb
WHERE cardId = 'A1' AND
      cb.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                 FROM cardBalances cb2
                 WHERE cb2.cardId = 'A1' AND cb2.unit = cb.unit
                );
```

This has the advantage that it can use an index on `cardBalances(unit, CardId, date)`.

Comment: Thanks, your query is meaningful and works as expected. But I didn't quite understand why this same query returns different results. I get that they become indeterminate rows but it's the fact that versions handle this in a different way.

Comment: Grouping with just using `*` takes the top row. However, sql is working on sets (unordered) of tuples, unless specifically ordered. your subquery might be explicitly ordered, your query however sees a temporary result, which is a table, and it should group it ...  if the table is sorted or not is at that point irrelevant. So the result is indeterminate and it wouldn't even work in other database systems, because `*` is not an aggregate column in your query. mysql is ... sloppy. and now you have to do real sql ^^

Comment: different versions with different results: could be optimization, btw. ordering is usually expensive, so if there is no necessity to do it ... don't do it ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective by adding a row number based on the `cardId`, `unit` and descending order of `date`.

**Query**

```
select t1.unit, t1.balance from 
(
    select cardId, unit, balance, `date`, 
    (
        case unit when @curA
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := unit end 
    ) + 1 as num 
    from cardBalances t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by cardId, unit, `date` desc 
)t1 
where t1.num = 1
order by t1.unit;
```

[**`SQL Fiddle Demo`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfb83/1)

Comment: Sorry but unlike your fiddle, in MySQL this query returns multiple rows with mixed, incorrect balances. We expect 2 rows with unchanged balance.